# Does django-cors-headers allow access from all origins to the admin site?

Tags: django, cors

I am working on a Django app with DRF and I added CORS configuration using the django-cors-headers package recommended in the documentation.

I will set the origin to be my client on the production. My question is, will the admin site be available to public access from all browsers with this setup?

This is the production settings I am planning on using.

```py
# CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ['client origin']
```

I cannot test this atm because I am far from being ready for production.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is only for when you want resources on your site to be available on webpages on other domains. For example when your frontend is running on example.com and your Django backend on api.example.com, your browser might block calls to api.example.com, so for that you would need to add example.com to CORS_ORIGIN_WHIITELIST.

This does not have any effect on webpages that run on the same domain as your Django backend, so unless you have some complex configuration for your resources, the admin site should work as expected.